# Efficient CUDA FFT with a spike

Tags: cuda, fftw

I have a fixed array populated with some values and I am trying to perform convolution of this array with a spike in frequency domain. Spike means all of the values inside the array is zero except at one place e.g a=[0,0,1,0,0,]
I have to create this spike approximately 1 million times .. the value 1 being placed at different index everytime...

```
float *spike = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*len);
memset(spike,0,sizeof(float)*len);
void compute_spike(float *spike, int ind)
{
  spike[ind] = 1.0;

}
```

How can I create cufft complex type spike array on GPU efficiently ? You can also assume that I have an array of 1 million indices .. what is the best strategy to perform this convolution ? Should I create this spike on host and then move and do fft, convolve and ifft ? or should i create it on the fly on GPU how ?

Answer (score 2):

Given the large bandwidth differences between the PCI-e bus and GPU memory, it makes much more sense to perform the whole construction in GPU memory. I would suggest fusing the memset operation and the spike assignment into a single kernel, something like

```
template<typename T>
__global__
void compute_spike(T* gpu_spike, int index, int N, T val)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    for(; tid < N; tid += stride)  gpu_spike[tid] = (tid == index) ? val : T(0);
}
```

[Note: code written in browser, never compiled or run, use a own risk]

This uses the [grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) design pattern, you can read more about it at the blog link. Note that you code uses float, but your text mentions "cufft complex type" so I have presented the code as a template. Modify it as you see fit. This should be close in performance to a `cudaMemset` call, but reduces latency by fusing everything together

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also what if the size of this spike array is less than 10,000 ... would a monolithic kernel with if condition  give better performance than grid-stride loop design ?

Comment: It should make no difference